# How to handle expired free-accounts in a SaaS environment

Tags: database, saas, account

This is a bit philosophical, however, here is the scenario and the related question.
Suppose you sell premium accounts and at the same time offer time-limited free accounts.
Users register and log in using their email address. Creating a free account does not require handing over any overly sensitive data (just the email).
Free users have X days to evaluate your service then either upgrade to a premium account or see their free account expire.

The question is: how to best handle that "expired" database-wise?

You could:

1) keep the account in your global "user" table marking it is as expired

- PRO: username/email is always unique and one cannot re-register with
  the same email
- CON: one cannot re-register with the same email (maybe
  he wants to do just that after a new feature he is interested in is
  added)
- PRO: all accounts are in one place, easier handling of stats
  retrieval
- CON: user table can only get bigger over time

2) remove the account, possibly moving it to a user_history or expired_user table

- PRO: your user table is smaller and contains only data from "live" users
- CON: username/email of an expired account is re-usable (your logs are likely to get messed up, and you have to always log the userID other then the username since that would not be unique anymore)
- PRO: username/email of an expired account is re-usable (expired users that want to give the trial another run after new features are added can do so without being forced to pick another email address)
- CON: user stats gathering gets more complicated

Has anyone faced the same problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest splitting the schema into two:

```
TABLE: users
user_id (PK)
email_address
password_hash
....

TABLE: user_status
user_status_id (PK)
user_id (FK)
status_date
status_value
```

The current status of a given account is the one with the latest status date. 
When the user signs up for a "free" account, you insert a record into user_status with status value "new_free_status"; when the account expires, you insert a record with status value "free_account_expired". You use the status to check whether a user can log in or not; if you want to allow people to sign up at least one month after their free account last expired, you check the user status record to see when their account was closed.

You can, of course, create another lookup table called "status", and join to a table with "account_type" - that way, your data becomes more self-describing.

The key thing in this design is that you want to separate the user profile from the current status, and keep track of that status over time. This allows you to answer questions like "how many people signed up for a paid account after having a trial?", "how long between signing up for a free account do people upgrade?", "how many users come back for another trial?" etc.

Answer (score 3):

Having a user table that is too large shouldn't be a problem - storage is cheap, and if it's indexed well, you'll be fine. I'm currently speccing out a similar application, and we're just going to keep all accounts in the user table. If the user has let their trial lapse for more than a month or so, we just let them sign up again to check out the new features if they want, and we just reactivate their account.

This strategy works well of course, because of the type of application. You would typically use it on a daily basis; you'd never use our application for a few hours and throw it away again. This is why it makes sense for us, but it doesn't make sense for Adobe to do this with Photoshop, for example.

What I've said may not apply to your situation, but I (and I can only assume other developers) consider it to be a bad practice to use multiple tables to slice data into categories. Use a column and a `WHERE` clause to do this, it's what they're for.